# R - Expanding Product Based on Previous Result

Tags: r, if-statement

I am relatively new to R and am trying to write a code for:

c=n1(n1-R_1-1)(n1-R_1-R_2-2)...(n1-R_1-R_2-...-R_{m1-1}-m1+1)

I essentially want to create a vector containing all possible values of c. Note that n1 and m1 are fixed values.

Here is my attempt:

```
c[j]<- for (j in 1:m1)
{
 if (c==1) {n}
 else (c>1) {n(n-R_1-1)}
}
```

I know this is wrong. I am struggling with the structure. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are R1, R2.. ?

Comment: They are some value that is given. For example, 3. They will always be an integer. If that makes a difference for what you thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unsure about what you are asking. But does this solve the issue?

```
    m1 = 8
    n = 6
    c <- numeric(m1)
    R_1 <- 3

    for (j in 1:m1){
      if (j==1) {c[j] <- n}
      else {c[j]<- c[j-1]*(c[j-1]-R_1-1)}
    }
```

Comment: I believe this idea will resolve my problem. I had no clue numeric was a thing. It looks like nifty tool. I will try implementing into my code. The main change I am going to make is for the last 1 in the else statement. I'm going to use (j-1). Thank you!

Comment: Good to know. Could you please mark it as the correct answer if it solved the problem. Thanks